# How to set Image Zoom in click Or pen Responding in React Native

Tags: react-native, image-processing

I'm try to add Image Zooming/Zoom out in my application but the problem is that when I'll be implement pen Controller Zoom in/zoom out it work but when I try to onPress method for zoom in & zoom out it not working

```
<DoubleClick onPress={() => this.handleClick()}>
    <ZoomableImage source={{uri: 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b7/b2/39/b7b2394dbd5b13707100546ad3bd4bda--st-michael-poster.jpg',width: 100,height: 100,}}/>
</DoubleClick>
```

I'm try do developer Double click, Image will be Zoom then use of pan to more zoomin zoom out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll Got the solution for this `react-native-photo-view`

```
import PhotoView from 'react-native-photo-view';

<PhotoView
      source={{uri: 'https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/react-1-logo-png-transparent.png'}}
      minimumZoomScale={0.5}
      maximumZoomScale={3}
      androidScaleType="fitCenter"
      style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}/>
```